# Mongoose strict mode true is not working for nested object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this Schema

```
const TransportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true
  },
  driver: {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: String,
    registrationId: String,
    name: String
  }
})
```

When I update the document using "updateOne" and a driver object like this:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
export default class User {
  public readonly id: String;
  public registrationId: String;
  public name: String;
  public username: String;
  public role: String;
  public passwordHash: String;
  public createdAt: Date;

  constructor(props: Omit<User, 'id'>, id?: String) {
    Object.assign(this, props);

    if(!id) {
      this.id = uuidv4();
    } else {
      this.id = id;
    }
  }
}

async assignDriver(id: String, driver: User): Promise<boolean> {
  const result = await MongoTransportModel.updateOne(
    { id }, 
    { driver, driverAssignedAt: Date.now() }
  );
  return !!result.nModified;
}
```

I don't want it to save the fields I haven't declared in the schema like "passwordHash", and it is saving. I tried to use `strict: true` and doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the code of where you are doing the update?